# Worklight for Samsung Pixelsense

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, pixelsense

Does anybody know if you can put Worklight generated content into Samsung Pixelsense (http://multitouch-hardware.eu/microsoft-surface-sur40/?lang=en), or if there can be any possible Worklight integration for this system/device?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This device is not operated by a platform supported by Worklight, so the answer is: IBM Worklight (any version) does not support PixelSense technology.

You can submit a request for enhancement: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html